# Undefined reference with tf and rospy

Tags: rospy, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am having a problem with an undefined reference when attempting to use `tf` with `rospy`.

The error message is:

```
[imu_cmp_sync_stick-16] process has died [pid 8677, exit code 1, cmd /home/mech801/catkin_ws/src/ros_opto22/src/imu_cmp.py imu1:=/imu_sync/stick_imu __name:=imu_cmp_sync_stick __log:=/home/mech801/.ros/log/6aec55c6-f1d8-11e3-a955-0002b333179f/imu_cmp_sync_stick-16.log].
log file: /home/mech801/.ros/log/6aec55c6-f1d8-11e3-a955-0002b333179f/imu_cmp_sync_stick-16*.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mech801/catkin_ws/src/ros_opto22/src/imu_cmp.py", line 46, in <module>
    import tf
  File "/home/mech801/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 28, in <module>
ImportError: /home/mech801/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/_tf.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console13g_initializedE
```

Clearly there is a problem with the linking of the function `ros::console::g_initialized()`. However, I am not sure how to fix it, as this is a Python program and I am getting a C++ linker error.

`catkin_make` works fine, even on a 100% clean `catkin_ws` directory (i.e. `devel` and `build` directories deleted before running `catkin_make` again).

The python code segment that causes the error is an `import tf` directive. This can be proved by running `python` and attempting to import `tf` at the command prompt.

```
>>> import tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mech801/catkin_ws/src/geometry/tf/src/tf/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _tf import *
ImportError: No module named _tf
```

Note that the `tf` package has been installed and its directory tree exists as `/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf`. I am not sure why it's trying to read it form my local `catkin_ws` directory tree.

Thanks,
Bart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173455/undefined-reference-with-tf-and-rospy/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have the geometry stack (which contains tf) checked out into you local workspace, and you have your local workspace set up as an overlay on the system install, which is why it's preferring your local copy over the system install of tf.

The tf python module is implemented in C++, which is why you can get dynamic linker errors when trying to load it.

There are two things that could be causing this linking error, both related to ABI problems:

- You've upgraded some of your ROS packages, but not all of them, and somewhere along the way an ABI problem crept in. This should go away if you do an `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` to install the latest versions of everything.
- You've upgraded your ROS packages since building tf, and the ABI of one of the packages it depends on has changed. You can try removing the build and devel folders in your workspace and rebuilding everything.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-06-12**:
Thanks, I'll have to check on the workspace overlays. To cut a long story short another package had defined its own implementation of `tf` which was being used ahead of the system one. Cleaning out the `catkin_ws/src` directory tree of all but essential modules fixed the problem.